# OpenVZ - updating kernel and all containers

Tags: linux, kernel, openvz, update

Last night I upgraded to the latest kernel of openvz. I rebooted the host node. It came up with the latest kernel. However, the containers are still running the old kernel.

What I did on the host node was reboot in CLI to cycle the machine. How do I get all the containers to cycle as well on a reboot?

Also, is the host node and other containers at a security risk if containers are running the old kernel still?

Comment: Ummm, with OpenVZ, the containers don't run their own kernels. There's only one kernel, and that's the one that the host runs. This is one of the primary detractors about OpenVZ versus other proper virtualization options, and is why I try and steer people away from it whenever possible.

Comment: Well when the system came back online, the containers it looks like were "put to sleep". they came back up with the older kernel till they were rebooted or maybe it was just a cache when I did uname -a.